# Why the cross spectra is differ in mlab and scipy.signal?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

I have two signals

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
import mpld3
from scipy import signal

mpld3.enable_notebook()

nfft = 256
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 30, dt)
nse1 = np.random.randn(len(t))  * 0.1              # white noise 1
nse2 = np.random.randn(len(t))  * 0.1              # white noise 2



# two signals with a coherent part and a random part
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*1*t) + nse1
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*1*t+np.pi) + nse2 

plt.plot(s1, 'r', s2, 'g')
plt.show()
```

I would like to get the coherence

```
cxy, fcoh = plt.cohere(s1, s2, nfft, 1./dt)
fcoh,cxy = signal.coherence(s1,s2, nfft=nfft, fs=1./dt)
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(fcoh, cxy)
#plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Coherence]

and the phase shift

```
(csd, f) = mlab.csd(s1, s2, NFFT=nfft, Fs=1./dt)
fig = plt.figure()
angle = np.angle(csd,deg =False)
angle[angle<-np.pi/2] += 2*np.pi

plt.plot(f, angle, 'g')
plt.hold(True)

(f, csd) = signal.csd(s1, s2, fs=1./dt, nfft=nfft)

angle = np.angle(csd,deg =False)
angle[angle<-np.pi/2] += 2*np.pi

plt.plot(f, angle,'r')


#plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to use `scipy` and `mlab`. Can anybody explain why do I get different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the two functions have different default values for some parameters.

For example, if you pass in to `plt.cohere()` the option `noverlap=128` you get an almost perfect match with the `numpy.signal()` solution:
[image]

Apart for a small mismatch at 0 Hz frequency, and we do not really care much about coherence of the DC components do we? I bet that if you dig deeper in the documentation of both you will find another smaller quirk in the standard values of the two.